# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView, RecyclerView after WebView under NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, webview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a **WebView** and **RecyclerView** under **LinearLayout** whose parent is **NestedScrollView**. Is this the right way to do, please refer to image.

I need a webview and to the bottom of webview I need a horizontal scroll view. It's to the end of webview and not placed at the end of the screen.

[image]

*Color legend*:

1. Yellow : Screen size
2. Red : Web view size
3. Blue : Horizontal recycler view

Crash I'm seeing,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for WebView
       at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
       at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

My Code,

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                </WebView>

                <TextView
                    style="@style/heading_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
                    android:paddingStart="16dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/resources" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_widgets"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:paddingStart="4dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Am I doing the right way or is it something wrongly implemented, If yes what would be the best way or alternative to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tough one, looks like you just can't use so heavy `View` like `WebView` inside `NestedScrollView` - [issueTracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=578150). you can try to set `webView.setLayerType` with software one, it may help if you are loading small page (just a guess)

Comment: @snachmsm Thanks for response. Let me check this, but problem is I'm not able to reproduce this crash, I'm getting crash report from users.

Comment: That didn't help.